# Which LaTeX editor is the best to use to make it easier to reference and produce a bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I used TeXstudio last year and I had a lot of trouble with referencing and producing a bibliography.

Reading around online, this is a widespread problem.

Which Latex editor is best to use to make it easier to produce a bibliography?

Comment: I am pretty sure this will be [AUCTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AUCTeX) in combination with [Jabref](http://www.jabref.org/#features).

Comment: Welcome. As long as you know how the process of getting a bibliography works, the editor in use really doesn't matter.

Comment: I know this may sound like a tangential comment, but this is one of the reasons that I like arara so much. I spend a bit of time configuring my editor to run arara, and then, once I've written the directives in the file, arara does the heavy lifting

Comment: What operating system does your computer use?

Comment: @mico windows 8.1

Comment: You may want to look into using WinEdt; the current version is 9.1; see winedt.com for more details. It's shareware, but quite affordable. A fabulous macro suite for WinEdt, called BibMacros, really simplifies editing and handling bib files. It may be downloaded for free from winedt.org -- see the last item in the table at http://www.winedt.org/Macros/LaTeX/.